# jquery code for removing called js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

$("script[src='assets/js/plugins/smooth-scrolling/jquery.simplr.smoothscroll.min.js']").remove();

I use this code to remove the plugin. by using this code it disappears from the page but the plugin is still working.Can anyone solve the problem please.

Comment: What is your plan by removing this script. do you want to stop slider which is running?

Comment: the plugin does not work with all browser even it effects webkit browser so i wanna remove it from webkit browser.

Comment: @ShamimTaifur better to include the script dynamically after detecting the browser

Comment: @Lakshay  Sorry, I can't understant. would you please explain what are you meaning.

Answer (score 5):

Call destroy method.

```
//Somewhere in your code, initialize carousel:
var owl = $("#owl-demo"),
owl.owlCarousel();

//some code...

//Now, you can destroy owl instance
owl.destroy();
```

You can find more info in Owl Carousel [website](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/#how-to).

Answer (score 0):

Its better to include the script after detecting the browser, rather than deleting it for a particular browser.

IMO, you should not include the script in the page by default. On page load, you should detect the browser, if the browser is compatible, load the script and make it work, otherwise, do something else.

Or even better, use the plugin which works with all browsers.

```
if($.browser.chrome) {
{
// include the script
$.getScript( "ajax/test.js", function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {

  console.log( "Load was performed." );

});

}
} else {
// do something else
}
```